Adding numerator to numerator and denominator to denominator of same class fractions still gives fraction of the same class
I apologize in advance if the question is too trivial.
I noticed that given a fraction of some class (e.g. $\frac{1}{2}$), if I add numerator and denominator of another fraction equivalent to the first one (for example $\frac{2}{4}$) to numerator and denominator of the first fraction I still obtain a fraction equivalent to the previous two, just as if I had multiplied numerator and denominator by the same quantity, i.e. $$\frac{1 + 2}{2 + 4} = \frac{3}{6} = \frac{1}{2}$$ thus giving the relation: $$\frac{a + c}{b + d} = \frac{e}{f}$$
where given that $\frac{a}{b}$ and $\frac{c}{d}$ are equivalent, also $\frac{e}{f}$ is equivalent to the previous two.
Since I don't remember such a property for fractions, I was wondering if this relation always hold and, therefore, is just a property I didn't know/recall or if things are different here

By "of the same class", do you mean "equal to each other"? It looks like you do, but that's not the usual language used.

The mediant inequality, that $\dfrac{a+c}{b+d}$ is between $\dfrac ab$ and $\dfrac cd$. (For positive $a,b,c,d$.)

Also, you probably don't remember it because you probably weren't taught it. First, because it's a situation that almost never arises. And second because "adding" fractions like this is a common mistake that teachers have to train students to not do, and pointing out the one weird case where it does work would only make that more difficult.

@JonathanZ Yes, I do. I'm sorry, in italian we say the fractions belong to the same "equivalent class", so I just used the same language. I'm going to clarify the question

Nessun problema!

Last comment from me: If you enjoy observations like this, you might enjoy reading about the "Farey sequence".

@JonathanZ
It actually looks really interesting, thanks!

I couldn't resist! I once read a really cool book about this, and I had to see if I could track it down again, and I did. It's called ".... The Mediant and the Farey Sequence", by Scott Guthery, and I highly recommend it.

Thanks a lot! Really appreciated!

It is true.  Note that $\frac ab = \frac cd$ guarantees that there is some $k$ (which may be a fraction itself) such that $c=ka, d=kb$.  Then
$$\frac {a+c}{b+d}=\frac {a+ka}{b+kb}=\frac {a(k+1)}{b(k+1)}=\frac ab$$
This works whenever $k \neq -1$

Did you mean $d = kb$? Not the downvoter btw.

@Student:  Yes, I did.  Thanks.

Thanks, very clear proof
